# Is this the right trick to keep a service alive even under low memory pressure?

Tags: android, android-service, low-memory

I used the following code to keep a service alive:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    keepServiceAlive(this, 2222);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void keepServiceAlive(Service service, int id) {
    Notification note = new Notification(0, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;        
    service.startForeground(id, note);
}
```

But sometimes the service was still being killed. Could you help me confirm the correctness of this piece of code, or would you offer a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a malformed `Notification` object. Android 4.3 will now show it's own `Notification` to the user when it detects this hack and the user will be informed that your service is running. If you really need it to be in the foreground, give it a proper icon and let your users know about your service, and explain why it's necessary. You might even consider allowing them to decide whether to have the service run as a foreground service via SharedPreferences.

See [this blog post by CommonsWare](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/07/30/notifications-foreground-services-android-4p3.html)

Comment: That makes sense. But the key issue here is: will your suggestion give more opportunity to make it alive under low-memory?

Comment: `startForeground()` is probably the best you could do. I suppose if you *really* wanted to you could run a repeating alarm that fires an intent to start the service, so if it's killed it will be restarted at the next alarm. I would seriously think about wether you really need to do this, because it might be something the user wants to turn off or not be so persistent.